# How to find correct row index in filtered WPF datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

We are working on a WPF application with VS 2015 using the WPF DataGrid.

In this DataGrid we have the possibility to filter rows which changes the DataGrids Items-collection (Unfiltered we have p.e. 100 items and filtered 20).

Further we can change data by a seperate edit dialog.

When that dialog is closed the data in the DataGrid shall be refreshed (by reading the data from the database and re-setting the source) and the SelectedIndex set to the index before the refresh.

While the DataGrid is unfiltered you would detect the index of the currently selected row by

```
int currentIndex = grid.Items.IndexOf(grid.CurrentItem);
```

or

```
int currentIndex = grid.SelectedIndex;
```

But when the grid is filtered we get wrong index in both cases.

Per example:
When the grid is filtered i edit the data of the first row, which is normally the forth in the items list (index = 3), but i get index = 0.
When i remind the SelectedIndex 0 in a variable and set it after the refresh, not the first item in the filtered grid is selected but the first item of the source.
When i get the SelectedItem and take a look at the properties i see that it is the wrong item.

Meanwhile i even tried that code proposed by Milan but without success:

```
var row = grid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(grid.SelectedIndex);
vm.RefreshList();
grid.SelectedIndex = grid.ItemContainerGenerator.IndexFromContainer(row);
```

In that case the variable row is disconnected after calling the method RefreshList.
And even before i get with IndexFromContainter the wrong index - 0 instead of 3.

How can we get the right index?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You *are* getting the right index. Which item do you want to select? Is the list filtered or unfiltered when you try to select the item?

Comment: @mm8: When i try it the list is filtered. I edited the first item in the filtered list, which has in unfiltered grid the index 3. In the filtered grid it has SelectedIndex 0. But when i set SelectedIndex after refresh to 0 i don't selected the first row of the filtered variant but of the the unfiltered. Meanwhile i have found out why this happens. After the refresh the Items contains the unfiltered list again. Just after i had setted SelectedIndex the filter of the grid is applied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, do you know such situations when the solution is right before your nose but you cannot see it?

This was my problem.

After the refresh of the datagrid's source the Items-collection was unfiltered.

When i set SelectedIndex to 0 i selected the first item of the unfiltered list.

Just after that the filter was re-applied.

So i made a few changes to my code.

Now i remind the SelectedItem and after the refresh i look within a foreach-loop for the item and - this time - i set the correct SelectedIndex.

Example:

```
MyItem currentItem = grid.SelectedItem as MyItem;
vm.RefreshList();
int n = 0;
foreach (MyItem item in grid.Items)
{
    if (item.pki == currentItem.pki)
    {
        grid.SelectedIndex = n;
        grid.Focus();
        break;
    }
    n += 1;
}
```

This works with filtered and unfiltered lists and even when data is sorted by a column (ascendant and descendant).

Comment: In my case I used Listbox.ItemsSource in the foreach to find the original/absolute index of the selected item from the filtered view of the listbox.

                //
                Object CurrentItem = DocumentsListLB.SelectedItem as Object;
                int n = 0;
                foreach (Object item in DocumentsListLB.ItemsSource)
                {
                    if (item == CurrentItem)
                    {
                        SelectedIndex = n;
                        break;
                    }
                    n += 1;
                }